# Get data from object in array in database on SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have a table where in a column (topics) i have this kind of array with objects inside (this array with objects is different for each row in the database):

topics colum in row1:

```
[
    {
        "topicId": "CON",
        "Dcentros": [
            {
                "dcentro_id": "9388TG",
                "dcentro_name": "9388TG"
            },
            {
                "dcentro_id": "9387OC",
                "dcentro_name": "9387OC"
            }
        ],
        "topicName": "CONFLUENCE"
    },
    {
        "topicId": "PMO",
        "Dcentros": [
            {
                "dcentro_id": "9387OC",
                "dcentro_name": "9387OC"
            }
        ],
        "topicName": "PMO"
    },
    {
        "topicId": "TSM",
        "Dcentros": [
            {
                "dcentro_id": "9387CC",
                "dcentro_name": "9387CC"
            }
        ],
        "topicName": "TSM"
    }
]
```

topics column in row2:

```
[
        {
            "topicId": "COS",
            "Dcentros": [
                {
                    "dcentro_id": "9388TG",
                    "dcentro_name": "9388TG"
                },
                {
                    "dcentro_id": "9387OC",
                    "dcentro_name": "9387OC"
                }
            ],
            "topicName": "CONNECTIONS"
        },
        {
            "topicId": "PTO",
            "Dcentros": [
                {
                    "dcentro_id": "9387OC",
                    "dcentro_name": "9387OC"
                }
            ],
            "topicName": "PTO"
        },
        {
            "topicId": "TAM",
            "Dcentros": [
                {
                    "dcentro_id": "9387CC",
                    "dcentro_name": "9387CC"
                }
            ],
            "topicName": "TAMIT"
        }
    ]
```

I would like to extract the "topicName" for each object inside the array from the different rows, if 'dcentro_id' exist inside the differents objects.

p.e:
(extract all the 'topicName' for the 'dcentro_id:9387CC')
**the result should be, and array with: 'TAMIT', 'TSM'**.

I did try this in MySQL:

```
SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(topics, '$[*].topicName') as c_name  FROM tool_bbdd.workspace WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(topics, '$[*].Dcentros[*].dcentro_id'), '$[*]') = '9387CC';
```

But not works fine, extract all the topics in the object, not just the topic where it exist.

Some help.
thanks

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to look like given the example JSON data above? What does it mean to extract a topic that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what results you want, but this will pick out only the elements with a specific `dcentro_id`.

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  tool_bbdd.workspace
CROSS JOIN
  JSON_TABLE(
    topics,
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
      topicRowID FOR ORDINALITY,
      topicId   VARCHAR(32) PATH '$.topicId',
      topicName VARCHAR(32) PATH '$.topicName',
      NESTED PATH '$.Dcentros[*]' COLUMNS (
        dcentroRowID FOR ORDINALITY,
        dcentro_id   VARCHAR(32) PATH '$.dcentro_id',
        dcentro_name VARCHAR(32) PATH '$.dcentro_name'
      )
    )
  )
    AS t
WHERE
  t.dcentro_id = '9387OC'
```

| topicRowID | topicId | topicName | dcentroRowID | dcentro_id | dcentro_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CON | CONFLUENCE | 2 | 9387OC | 9387OC |
| 2 | PMO | PMO | 1 | 9387OC | 9387OC |

Demo using MariaDB as MySQL seems to be broken on the site...

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f9cb6b30e8437022054bfa0a6a9bf91d